# Sequential Background Fetch Requests iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I am working on an application that uses background fetch to access a large number of RSS feeds and check for new results. I've done my best to optimize the parsing time in order to manage as many feeds as possible in the ~30s window that iOS gives you for background fetch.

In the case where a user may have 200+ RSS feeds, this operation will be taking more than 30s -> what is the best way to get around the 30s limit?

Is there a way to create sequential request methods, something such as storing the a "request number" in NSUserDefaults and deciding what to fetch at that time.

Ex:

```
Fetch 0 = first 50 feeds, set the Fetch# to 1 on completion.
Fetch 1 = second 50 feeds, set Fetch# to 2 on completion.
etc,
```

Is this the only way? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you only using `HEAD` requests or are you fetching data and parsing it?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm fetching and parsing the data, I want to be able to update the badge & local notification with the number of new results in the feeds.

Comment: You should perform `HEAD` requests first; they're much less expensive and have a "last updated" time. Once you find the feeds that are updated, request only those ones if you want to do further processing.

Comment: Thanks @IanMacDonald, that will help with finding which feeds to update, but in the even that ALL of them need to be updated, I will still need to break up the task somehow.

Comment: I feel like the granularity between 200 and 2000 new stories is a little unnecessary. If you get a response saying there are more feeds updated than you reasonably expect to process, just assume there's one story per updated feed and use that number.

Answer (score 1):

That solution is pretty smart and might work.

If i was in your position, i would delegate the task of fetching and parsing the feeds to a server in a cronjob of some kind that refreshes all feeds in the system at a set interval, leaving your client only to check if there are updates in the already parsed feed. You could keep a simple database with the feeds and the date of the last update which could be checked against the information on the iphone client.

The only other background mode that works in iOS longer than 30s is Background Transfer Service, i dunno if there is a way to get creative with that, but you could try.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. I don't have much experience with web dev, I wanted to keep it all on the device if possible hah.